# Performance issue on dataload SAS to Vertica

Tags: sas, vertica

Our organisation is in the process of migrating from PADB to Vertica.
We have some analyst who uses SAS.
I converted their tools and macros to be able to work from PADB to Vertica.
But when it comes to dataload from SAS to Vertica the perfomance is not the same as before.

I am seeing execution time from 1-2 minutes becoming 2-3 hours.

I am using the ODBC as I was not able to use other method like :

```
proc sql exec;
connect to odbc (datasrc=EDW authdomain=VERTICA);
execute(COPY CRM_COMMON.new_load_test FROM local 
'/data/saswork/SAS_work765E0000405D_cammsaim238/SAS_workB45C0000405D_cammsaim238/test1.csv' PARSER fcsvparser() ) by odbc;
disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

It's not working I'm getting a note :NOTE: No data found/modified.

I tried using proc append and proc dataset and proc copy everything is slow.
I tried using bulkload but it's not available.

Any idea on what I can do or try to speed up the data transfer?
Let me know! 
-------UPDATE----
I tried various other ways and still getting error, when I check the log there seems to be an issue with null values from my data ... any idea ?

```
proc sql exec;
 /* Loading converted csv file to ParAccel */ connect to odbc (datasrc=EDW authdomain=VERTICA); execute(COPY CRM_COMMON.new_load_test FROM local '/data/saswork/SAS_work765E0000405D_cammsaim238/SAS_workB45C0000405D_cammsaim238/test1.csv' DELIMITER ',' ) by odbc; 
disconnect from odbc; 
quit;
```

Comment: Is the path for the CSV file visible to the server where EDW (or VERTICA) is running?

Comment: yes it's visible I also managed to add the abort or error option and it's helping with the type of error rejecting the insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to load data with this :

I used the option abort on error to get more details about the error and also the reject option to see record that failed

utlimately the issue was with null values precisely with the timestamp
I havent found a fit all solution to load any type of data regard less of nulls and format but I managed to load data faster than using the ODBC

I tried the option trailing nullcols  but it's not helping with the null values

```
proc sql exec;
/* Loading converted csv file to ParAccel */
connect to odbc (datasrc=EDW authdomain=VERTICA);
execute(COPY CRM_COMMON.test_low    FROM local    '/data/saswork/SAS_work765E0000405D_cammsaim238/SAS_workB45C0000405D_cammsaim238/test_low.csv'  DELIMITER ','  abort on error 
    rejected data '/data/saswork/SAS_work765E0000405D_cammsaim238/SAS_workB45C0000405D_cammsaim238/reject_low.csv' ) by odbc;
disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

Comment: I'd also add the `EXCEPTIONS '/data/saswork/SAS_work765E0000405D_cammsaim238/SAS_workB45C0000405D_cammsaim238/test_low.log' ` clause and put a  `REJECTMAX 50 ` clause instead of your `ABORT ON ERROR` . This allows you to prepare for several different types of errors in one load attempt. And it's no wonder it takes much longer. Error management, when it becomes necessary, slows the COPY process down considerably.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks alot !!